# Use timestamp(or datetime) as part of primary key (or part of clustered index)

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, primary-key, clustered-index

I use following query frequently:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Timestamp > [SomeTime] AND Timestamp < [SomeOtherTime] and publish = 1 and type = 2 order by Timestamp
```

I would like to optimize this query, and I am thinking about put timestamp as part of primary key for clustered index, I think if timestamp is part of primary key , data inserted  in table has write to disk sequentially by timestamp field.Also I think this improve my query a lot, but am not sure if this would help.

```
table has 3-4 million+ rows.
timestamp field never changed.
I use mysql 5.6.11
```

Anothet point is : if this is improve my query , it is better to use timestamp(4 byte in mysql 5.6) or datetime(5 byte in mysql 5.6)?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

- An ideal index for this query would be `KEY (publish, type, Timestamp)`. By your choice of query I get that filtering by `publish` and `type` is common.
- If the above is correct, then data inserted into table will not be sequential by Timestamp anyhow
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is unique. Are you certain you are not allowed to have two identical `Timestamp` values? Remember that resolution is **1** second, so it is very common to have same `TIMESTMAP` values for different rows.
- I usually like an `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns as `PRIMARY KEY` (see [Reasons to use AUTO_INCREMENT columns on InnoDB](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reasons-to-use-auto_increment-columns-on-innodb)). Just use a normal index on `(publish, type, Timestamp)` is my general opinion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why didn't you provide the table structure and query explain plan ? Not all of us have a crystal ball :)
2. I believe that the publish and type columns don't have a great cardinality (number of distinct values), so you don't have an index on them. That will leave the requirement that the column Timestamp should be indexed in some way.
3. If you have an index on Timestamp, there's no need to include this column in the PK.
4. The idea of a clustered index, with Timestamp in PK to achieve data write sequential mode is nice, but it will increase the insert queries response time.
5. Please read this post about Timestamp VS Datetime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp